# player icon shows before the video thumbnail loads on video player

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to implement a video player in html page. Though everything works fine but before the page loads there is full page play icon grayed out. I want to remove that icon. I can't find a way to remove it. I have attached the image for the player. Any help appreciated...
Thanks.

[image: Here's the icon]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Android's default video element. You can add a `poster="url"` attribute so the poster image is shown instead.